# Send 'enter' to remote process with libssh

Tags: c++, ssh, libssh

I'm using libssh to log into a terminal and then run a ncurses application.

I'm following this tutorial, sending one character at the time:
http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_shell.html

The ncurses application waits for user input with getstr(), my problem is that when I write the input and press enter libssh sends '\n' rather than an enter signal, so the curses application crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use here document bash syntax. Your command which you send over libssh API will look something like this:

```
your_instruction <<tag\ntag
```

Study the [following examples](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).